# Multiple DateRangePicker in single component React

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I have DatePicker defined like this:

```
                    <DateRangePicker 
                        startDate={this.state.startDate}
                        startDateId={"start_date_id" + i.toString()}
                        endDate={this.state.endDate}
                        endDateId={"end_date_id" + i.toString()}
                        onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => 
                            this.setDateFilter(startDate, endDate, filter.propertyName) } 
                        focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} 
                        onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} 
                    />
```

This is rendered in loop. If I have single DateRangePicker - it works like it should. When there are more than 1 picker - calendar is not showed on click.

Is this possible to have multiple DateRangePicker's working on same state variables? I don't have any errors in console. I am using 'react-dates' for this.

Answer (score 0):

If anyones wonder - I needed to use dictionaries (focusedInput variable needes to be uniqe for every DatePicker it seems).